# Save path ('../mywebsite/images/$newname') in your database

Tags: javascript, php, database, image

I am trying to make a website, when user can make a screenshot using html2canvas and then after the screenshot is made, the user can save it to that website. I tried to follow this [tutorial:](http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/html2canvas-take-screenshot-of-web-page-and-save-it-to-server-javascript-and-php/) but I failed. It gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function strototime()
>   in /data/web/virtuals/148842/virtual/www/save.php:9 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in /data/web/virtuals/148842/virtual/www/save.php on
>   line 9

Because I dont know how to save path in my database, acording this:

> When you save the image with the code I shared, (Line:
>   file_put_contents('img.png', $unencodedData);), there's an actual
>   image on the server named "img.png".
>
> All you have to do is move it to wherever you want with
>   move_uploaded_file() function like this: move_uploaded_file('img.png',
>   '../mywebsite/images/$newname');
>
> Then save the new path ('../mywebsite/images/$newname') in your
>   database so you can access it later.

This is my code:

Save.php

```
<?php
//Get the base-64 string from data
$filteredData = substr($_POST['img_val'], strpos($_POST['img_val'], ",") + 1);

//Decode the string
$unencodedData = base64_decode($filteredData);

//Save the image
file_put_contents('img_' . strototime() . '.png', $unencodedData);

move_uploaded_file('img.png', './posters/$newname');

?>
<h2>Save the image and show to user</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="img.png" target="blank">
                Click Here to See The Image Saved to Server</a>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <a href="index.php">
                Click Here to Go Back</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>
                Here is Client-sided image:
            </span>
            <br />
<?php
//Show the image
echo '<img src="' . $_POST['img_val'] . '" />';
?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<style type="text/css">
body, a, span {
    font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

Index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js"></script>

<h2>Simple Implementation of html2canvas With JavaScript and PHP</h2>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save.php" id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="img_val" id="img_val" value="" />
</form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Take Screenshot Of Div Below" onclick="capture();" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <a href="http://www.kubilayerdogan.net?p=304" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold;">
                            Documentation (Back to Site)</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="padding: 10px;">
            <b>Div:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="target">
                <table cellpadding="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            This is sample implementation
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            It can hold form values:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="form_value" value="" placeholder="Try me" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Simple Button Element:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button name="my_button">
                                Clicking Me Useless</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            Let's go with CSS:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="aside">
                                <h3>Aside heading</h3>
                                <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit!</p>
                            </div>
                            <div id="more">
                                <h2>My first styled page</h2>
                                <p>Welcome to my styled page!</p>
                                <p>It lacks images, but at least it has style.</p>
                                <p>There should be more here, but I don't know what yet.</p>
                                <address>
                                    Made 5 April 2004
                                    <br />
                                    by myself.
                                </address>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Try Image:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="soc.jpeg" alt="SOC" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function capture() {
        $('#target').html2canvas({
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
                $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
                //Submit the form manually
                document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #target {
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    h2, h3 {
        color: #003d5d;
    }
    p {
        color:#AA00BB;
    }
    #more {
        font-family: Verdana;
        color: purple;
        background-color: #d8da3d;
    }
</style>
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: you have to pass a date in strtotime(), to give append it into the name of image @user7176800

Comment: Can You please help me with that? I am totaly new to this and I really dont know what am I doing...

Comment: strtotime(date()),try this. add this insead of strtotime() @user7176800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a blatant typo on line 9 of your code, if you read the error you would know this.

```
file_put_contents('img_' . strototime() . '.png', $unencodedData);
```

Should be:

```
file_put_contents('img_' . strtotime() . '.png', $unencodedData);
```

Edit: 
Looks like you are trying to create a random filename based on a timestamp, so just use `date("U")` instead...:

```
file_put_contents('img_' . date("U") . '.png', $unencodedData);
```

Comment: I repaired it, now it says this: Warning: strtotime() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in /data/web/virtuals/148842/virtual/www/save.php on line 9

Comment: You need to pass it a date so it has something to convert and return....   If you just want a timestamp use `date('U')` which returns a unix timestamp.

Comment: So now, it should looks like this? I dont know... file_put_contents('img_' . strtotime(date('U')) . '.png', $unencodedData) ;

Comment: Thank You, now that error is gone, but still there is no picture saved in the "posters" folder on my hosting. I tought it should save to that folder after I take the screenshot... I thought that this line of code should do that... move_uploaded_file('img.png', './posters/$newname');

Comment: Make sure you have write permission to that directory of course

Comment: no, on the actual filesystem, make sure your `pictures` directory can be written to by the web server (probably `www-data` or `apache` or `wheel` or...)

Comment: I tried to change atributes of that file to 777, but when I try to visit it via browser it gives me: Forbidden You don't have permission to access /posters/ on this server. and when I take the screenshot, the image is created in "www" folder, not inside "posters" folder...

Comment: Thats a different issue to this original question, i'd suggest closing this question off (marking as correct if it answered your original query) and opening a new one, so you can elaborate further on the issue.

Comment: Is it possible to make something like this? file_put_contents(.PathToFolder/'img_' . date("U") . '.png', $unencodedData);

Comment: Indeed, but that looks incorrect syntax, try:  `file_put_contents('./pathToFolder/img/' .date("U") .'.png');`

Comment: Thanks, but it seems there is some problem: file_put_contents() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /data/web/virtuals/148842/virtual/www/posters/save.php on line 9

Comment: I tried this: `file_put_contents('./pathToFolder', 'img_' .date("U") . '.png');` but it show this error: `Warning: file_put_contents(./nove): failed to open stream: Is a directory in /data/web/virtuals/148842/virtual/www/posters/save.php on line 9`

Comment: The actual data will be the second argument: `file_put_contents('./pathToFolder/img/' .date("U") .'.png', $theData);`

Comment: To understand: img is not a folder, it is part of the name of every picture: every picture name starts with img_ so the whole name looks like this: "img_randomNumber.png" and I am trying to put it to folder "./pathToFolder"